# Improving this genetic algorithm for error minimization

Tags: python, algorithm, mathematical-optimization, genetic-algorithm, evolutionary-algorithm

I've written a simple genetic algorithm, designed to perform fitting. That is, given some input `f(x)`, I'm able to solve for `x` without knowing `f` (and, really, an `f(x)` doesn't *have* to even exist). My process is as follows:

1. I generate some initial points, uniformly distributed across the known solution interval `0,1`.
2. I then iterate, until I reach some some maximum number of generations. With each iteration, I:

   a) Sort the current set of points by minimum error (RSS error), store them in the `parents` list

   b) Keep the first `500`, and throw in a few randomly selected points from the initial list

   c) 1/2 of points from the `parents` list I "smear", by generating a new point distributed plucked from a Gaussian with a mean given by the chosen point

   d) I now fill the remaining "empty slots" in the `parents` list by producing "children". Children are produced by randomly selecting two points from the `parents` list, and taking their mean (`(male + female)/2`).

   e) Finally, I set the initial list equal to the parents list, and jump back to a)

In the end, I sort the list one final time, and select the first element to be the solution.

**See code below**

I end up with a somewhat-ok solution. It seems to jump surprisingly quickly to the neighborhood of the solution, but then fails to make much progress from there. I still obtain better (and *faster*) results using brute-force. So, I'd like to improve my algorithm.

**A couple notes:**

I'm well aware that this depends, to some extent, on the problem I'm applying the algorithm to. I'm interested in using this for a few different things. Ignoring the problem, what can I do with *what I have* to improve this?

I'm also aware better/easier/faster/etc methods (probably) exist. I'm just interested in the topic.

**My code:**

```
        initial = []

        # Generate random initial test points
        for i in range(5000):
            initial.append(random.uniform(0,1))

        for i in range(max_generations):
            # Sort according to some error function
            initial.sort(key = error_func)

            # Keep the "best" 500
            parents = initial[:500]

            # Throw in a few random points
            for i in range(randint(10,100)):
                parents.append(initial[randint(0,len(parents) - 1)])

            # "Mutate" half the parents
            for individual in parents:
                if randint(0,1):
                    individual = random.gauss(individual, 1E-5)

            children = []

            while len(children) < (5000 - len(parents)):
                # Randomly pick a male and female
                male = parents[randint(0, len(parents) - 1)]
                female = parents[randint(0, len(parents) - 1)]

                # Produce a child
                children.append((male + female) / 2) 

            parents.extend(children)
            initial = parents

     initial.sort(key = error_func)
     print(initial[0])
```

**Some points I'm considering:**

1. I know there are several different ways genetic algorithms choose the "fittest" points (individuals/members/etc). Perhaps there's a better way than just sorting by least error?
2. Is it generally better to have more starting points, or more iterations/generations?

**Goals**

#1: Improve accuracy and precision
#2: Improve speed with which a "nice" solution is found

Answer (score 1):

Genetic algorithm must be operated in a system. So, you must specify some critical points before implementation. They are:

1. Population size (cout of chromosomes in each generation)
2. Selection operator
3. Crossover operator
4. Elistism rate
5. Mutation policy
6. Termination condition (fitness based or generation based)

Your decisions completely related with your problem try to solve (fitness function).

Main issue in the genetic algorithm is monotonly. If you cannot provide diversity, most probably you will stuck in local optima points. The solution is choosing **convenient "selection" and "crossover" operators**.

It may be start point for you, [comparison of selection operators](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/genetic_algorithms/genetic_algorithms_parent_selection.htm) and [comparion of crossover operators](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/genetic_algorithms/genetic_algorithms_crossover.htm). In addition, there are  [implementation ways of lots crossovers](http://www.tomaszgwiazda.com/1pointx.htm). Again, they are only introduction. You can find more resource, simply google it.